# PostgreSQL. Import data skip n lines

Tags: postgresql, import, insert, copy

I would like to know how I can import my data to table. I know the `COPY` command and the option `HEADER`. But the file I have to import has the following format:

```
Line 1: header1, header2, header3,... 
Line 2: vartype, vartype, vartype,... 
Line 3: data1, data2,...
```

Like you can see, I need to skip the second line too. For example:

```
"phonenumber","countrycode","firstname","lastname"
INTEGER,INTEGER,VARCHAR(50),VARCHAR(50)
123456789,44,"James","Bond"
5551234567,1,"Angelina","Jolie"
912345678,34,"Antonio","Banderas"
```

The first line is the exact name of the table's columns. I have tried to use the `INSERT INTO` command but I have not got good result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using these two strategies for this type of problem:

1) Import all

- import all rows into temporary table where columns have `varchar` type
- delete rows you do not want
- insert data into final table, cast `varchar` to desired types

2) Pre-process

- delete rows from imported file
- import

For your case, you can delete 2nd line using `sed` for example:

```
sed -i '2d' importfile.txt
```

This will remove 2nd line from file named `importfile.txt`. Note that flag `-i` will overwrite the file immediately, so use it with care.

You can use this to delete range of lines:

```
sed -i '2,4d' importfile.txt
```

This will remove lines 2, 3, 4 from file.

Comment: Yikes someone needs to raise an issue for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in a Linux shell you could always just stream in the records you want, eg

```
tail -[number of lines minus header] <file> | psql <db> -c "COPY <table> FROM STDIN CSV;"
```

or if your header is marked by say "#"

```
grep -v "^#" <file> | psql <db> -c "COPY <table> FROM STDIN CSV;"
```

Comment: Hi, do you have in mind an equivalent solution for a windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pre-process the file I'm afraid. There are far too many strange formats (like this one) around for COPY to understand - it just concentrates on handling the basics. You can trim the second line out with a simple bit of sed or perl.

```
perl -ne 'print unless ($.==2)' source_file.txt
```